# How do you query a website in vb6?

Tags: vba, vb6, excel

What is the function to query the web from vb6?

What I am trying to do is to get data from yahoo finance. For example this url returns a csv file with the dividend value of General Electric:

http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=GE&f=d

I need to run this in a function and have the function return the answer.

Comment: It may not be obvious if you aren't familiar with the [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service#Representational_state_transfer_.28REST.29) jargon, but your question is very similar to this question [how to do HTTP get and post to a RESTful web service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516119/get-post-to-restful-web-service). I think you'll find the answers useful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alternative to inet & webbrowser control to retrieve HTML only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624871/alternative-to-inet-webbrowser-control-to-retrieve-html-only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speaking of Excel, you can [create a web query](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/get-and-analyze-data-from-the-web-in-excel-HA001054848.aspx). Would be trivial in your case.

Other than that, you can use the [WinHttpRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384106(VS.85).aspx) if you want to make your life a bit easier, or a socket if you don't. But then, there's no winsock control in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

For a simple GET request like this in VB6 you can also create a small UserControl that invokes its *AsyncRead* method.  Such a control can perform multiple requests in parallel if desired, each one tagged with a *PropertyName* string for recognition when the results are returned.

Whichever approach you use be sure to set the options to bypass the local cache.  Otherwise repeated queries will return the same value each time.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [WinHttp.WinHttpRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384079(VS.85).aspx) COM object. And here's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940237/conversion-of-vb6-http-request-to-vb-net-2-0) which provides an example.