# Alternative to inet & webbrowser control to retrieve HTML only?

Tags: vb6

I would like to download *only* the HTML code in my VB6 program.
`Webbrowser` control is good but it hangs and also it has issues such as needing to disable the JavaScript, pic, etc in order to get just the HTML

The `Inet` control is better, but it is "buggy"

Is there any other control ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Download File - VB6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976152/download-file-vb6)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want to download the HTML of a page, you can easily use `Winsock` control.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
  Winsock1.Connect "stackoverflow.com", 80
End Sub

Private Sub Winsock1_Close()
  Winsock1.Close
End Sub

Private Sub Winsock1_Connect()
  Winsock1.SendData "GET /questions/8624871/vb6-alternative-to-inet-webbrowser-control HTTP/1.1" & vbCrLf & "Host: stackoverflow.com" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
End Sub

Private Sub Winsock1_DataArrival(ByVal bytesTotal As Long)
  Dim s As String

  Winsock1.GetData s, vbString
  RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text & s
End Sub
```

Comment: Hrm, this is a better solution. I should have actually read the question... +1

Comment: How to knw how much percent the page is downloaded??

Comment: @NokImchen There should be `Content-Length: XXXXX` in the header, to which you can compare the accumulated values of `bytesTotal`. If there's no `Content-Length` in the header, then you only know it's done when the connection is closed.

Comment: The Inet control isn't really buggy but it does have its quirks.  Better than rolling your own HTTP though you might consider the various HTTP requests that are already in Windows (WinHTTP, XMLHTTP, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is to host [WebKit.NET](http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/) in your VB 6 application just like you would any other .NET control.

Although it is a .NET control, which means that it won't work natively out-of-the-box with VB 6, it is possible to use controls developed in .NET with a VB 6 application. Microsoft provides the [Interop Forms Toolkit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ms788241) as an interoperability mechanism between the two languages.

Essentially, you'll use one of the .NET languages (it doesn't have to be VB.NET; you could also use C#) to create an ActiveX DLL containing your `UserControl` and register it for COM interop. Then, you can add this ActiveX control to your VB 6 project and hook up to handle the events it raises.

You can find a more complete sample on how to do this [here on CodeProject](http://65.39.148.34/KB/vb-interop/UsingDotNETControlsInVB6.aspx), or [here on CodeGuru](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_misc/com/article.php/c6747).

Indeed this approach is not going to be trivial to implement. But I suspect that it's your only alternative to the bundled `WebBrowser` control, considering that IE was pretty much dominating the browser market back when VB 6 was popular and no one is developing new controls for VB 6 anymore.

Comment: Looking back on this, I see that I misinterpreted the question (in my defense, it was edited; [the original](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8624871/1) was less than clear). Some of the other solutions are *much* better for this specific task. However, I won't delete my answer, as it may be useful to others who hit other limitations of the built-in WebBrowser control.

Comment: yes I'm glad you didn't delete your solution as it answers one I have. I have found a lot of your answers very helpful down the years, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need API calls, you don't need `WinSock`, you don't need `Inet`, you don't need WebKit interop. Just do it the easy way, using native VB6 code. Here's an excellent [article by Karl Peterson](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2008/03/27/simple-asynchronous-downloads.aspx) with sample code.

Answer (score 2):

This is good code, and it works even in ASP, VBScript.

```
Function GetHTMLCode(strURL) As String
    Dim strReturn                   ' As String
    Dim objHTTP                     ' As MSXML.XMLHTTPRequest
    If Len(strURL)=0 Then EXIT FUNCTION
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    objHTTP.open "GET", strURL,False
    objHTTP.send                    'Get it.
    strReturn =objHTTP.responseText
    Set objHTTP = Nothing 
    GetHTMLCode = strReturn 
End Function
```

Now call this function like this (always write with protocol):

```
Msgbox GetHTMLCode("http://www.stackoverflow.com")
```